# Find increasing values by year

Tags: sql-server, finance, trend

I have a table that contains a list of debts owed by customers. I need to write a SQL query to find which customers have an increasing amount of debt each year. Basically, I am trying to find the "bad apples", the people who continually get debts, in an increasing amount, every year. I suppose I am looking for a trend?

I have created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f38da/1) with some sample data. In the example, I don't care about customerId 2174 as they have only had two debts, many years ago, however, customerId 5218 has had an increasing amount of debts over the last 3-4 years.

Ideally, I'd like a list of customerIds that show a "trend" of increasing quantity of debts. i.e. they have 1 in 2015, 5 in 2016, 30 in 2017 etc.

Comment: you need to be specific on the condition.` had an increasing amount of debts over the last 3-4 years` is too general and from the sample data, i don't really see a `increasing` trend in debts at all. Or are you referring to the `amount` ?

Comment: I’m referring to the quantity of debts. As in, a single customer is continuously getting debts every year.

Comment: so what is the specific condition that you need ?

Comment: Not necessarily a “condition”, I’d like to use this in a report of some sort, right now, I just want a list of customers that have an increasing number of debts, over the years.

Comment: How many years ? When you write a query, you can't write a query with a general `increasing number of debts, over the years` condition. You need to be specific

Comment: I guess it would just be all the years that the customer had debt for?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: A list of customerIds that show a "trend" of increasing quantity of debts. i.e. they have 1 in 2015, 5 in 2016, 30 in 2017 etc.

Comment: then i guess you need to update your input in fiddle with some more relevant data, since none of your record seems increasing count of debt.

Comment: I've added some more data to the Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f38da/1

Comment: and post your expected output in above question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this.

```
; with cte as 
(SELECT customerId
      ,YEAR(debtDate) AS debtYear
      ,COUNT(*) AS debtCount
FROM dbo.Debts
   -----   apply year filter over there if want to select record for particular year range
GROUP BY YEAR(debtDate)
        ,customerId
)
, CT AS 
(
      SELECT C.* FROM CTE AS C 
      CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT * FROM CTE AS CC 
            WHERE C.customerId=CC.customerId
                AND C.debtYear>CC.debtYear 
                AND C.debtCount>=CC.debtCount
                ) AS D
)
SELECT DISTINCT customerId FROM CT  --- IF NEED JUST CUSTOMER NAME
------- OR IF NEED ALL DETAILS ADD debtYear, debtCount COLUMN
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I was after, just couldn't work it out in my head...

Comment: @TaylorN: mention not... ;)